# Ошибка при уничтожении сессии

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_login']))
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['email'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['btn_logout']))
    {
        session_destroy();
    }
```

В первый раз нажимаю на кнопку зарегистрироваться, сессия стартует. Появляется кнопка выйти. Когда нажимаю на неё обрабатывается второе условие и сессия должна уничтожится, но появляется ошибка (Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session in). Но ведь сессию я запустил в первой проверке условия. Почему не удаляется сессия?

Comment: Сессию надо запускать каждый раз при каждом исполнении скрипта.

Comment: Перед уничтожение прописать session_start() ?

Comment: пропишите перед условием

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы сессия создавалась только при нажатии на кнопку логин. Перед условием не подходит

Comment: Какая разница где стартует сессия? Обычно ее стартуют прямо в первых строках скрипта, а не по какому-то условию.

Answer (score 2):

Как правильно заметили в комментариях, стартуйте сессию до каких либо условий, а вот значения присваивайте уже по условию.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['btn_login'])) {
    $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['email'];
}
if(isset($_POST['btn_logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
}
```

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы сессия создавалась только при нажатии на кнопку логин. Перед условием не подходит. Зачем мне стартовать сессию если кнопка ВХОДА не нажата.
Задание именно такое